# Объединение значений в словаре

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, итераторы

Пишу метод, который бы брал на вход словарь, проверял, хранятся ли ключи в значениях других ключей, если да - объединял бы оба списка значений. 
Пример:

```
total = {'a': ['b', 'd'], 'b': ['c', 'd'], 'c': ['d']}


keys = list(total.keys())
values = list(total.values())
flag = 0
while flag == 0:
    if len(keys) == 1:
        flag = 1
        print(total)
    else:
        for k in keys:
            for ind, v in enumerate(values):
                if k not in v:
                    continue 
                else: 
                    total[keys[ind]] = total[k] + total[keys[ind]] 
                    values = values.remove(total[k])
                    del total[k]
                    keys = keys.remove(k)
                    keys
out: {'a': ['d', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'd']}
```

Код срабатывает, но не с первого запуска, а со второго-третьего. Причем, первые два запуска выдают ошибку(то есть я запускаю одну и ту же ячейку подряд 1-2 раза с ошибкой, а с 3-го раза запускается нормально):

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Объясните новичку, в чем дело и как пофиксить эту проблему. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Совет: `while flag == 0` -> `while not flag`. `flag = 0` -> `flag = False`, `flag = 1` -> `flag = True`. Да и тело в `else` у условия `if k not in v:` можно было вытащить -- на условие и так прерываете итерацию и переходите на следующую, поэтому условие можно было распрямить

Comment: @gil9red спасибо. если честно, не поняла, что значит распрямить условие)

Comment: Смотрите, вы пишите if/else, при этом в if у вас вызывается что-то из break/continue/return, т.е. попадание в if обязательно прерывает выполнение следующего кода, поэтому в этом случае `else` не нужен и можно ограничиться только if'ом, а тело в `else` сдвинуть влево, чтобы уменьшить ветвление, т.е. распрямить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `remove` возвращает `None`:

```
values = values.remove(total[k])
keys = keys.remove(k)
```

Не нужно переписывать значения переменных, правильно так:

```
values.remove(total[k])
keys.remove(k)
```

---

Интересно было попробовать алгоритм, вроде бы работает:

```
total = {'a': ['b', 'd'], 'b': ['c', 'd'], 'c': ['d']}

for k in total:
    for k1, v1 in total.items():
        if k == k1 or v1 is None or k not in v1:
            continue

        # Объединение значений
        total[k1] += total[k]

        # Обнуление значения у поглощенного ключа
        total[k] = None


print(total)  # {'a': ['b', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'd'], 'b': None, 'c': None}

total = {k: v for k, v in total.items() if v is not None}
print(total)  # {'a': ['b', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'd']}
```

Comment: Все работает, спасибо! Извините, что так поздно отметила ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, что не забыли мой ответ :D

Comment: забыла вообще-то лол, сейчас зашла и увидела)